# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used (flutter error)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add an audio player in flutter app but I am facing this issue when I am using a var to store audioplayer state and then trying to use it in if condition.
I am facing this issue res variable in the below code.
Also check the Image [image]

Below is the complete code

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class audio_player extends StatefulWidget {
  const audio_player({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<audio_player> createState() => _audio_playerState();
}

class _audio_playerState extends State<audio_player> {
  @override

  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  Duration duration = Duration();
  Duration position = Duration();
  bool playing = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          slider(),
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              getAudio();
            },
            child: Icon(
              playing == false ?
                  Icons.play_arrow :
                  Icons.pause,
              size: 50,
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  Widget slider(){
    return Slider.adaptive(
        min: 0.0,
        value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value){
          setState((){
            audioPlayer.seek(Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
          });
        }
    );
  }

  Future<void> getAudio() async {
    var url = "https://file-examples.com/storage/fe0b804ac5640668798b8d0/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3";

    if(playing){

      var res = await audioPlayer.pause();

      if(res==1){
        playing=false;
      }

    }
    else
      {
        var res = await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(url));

        if(res==1){
            playing = true;
        }
      }
    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      duration = dd;
    });
    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      position = dd;
    });
  }

}
```

I have copied this code from an old youtube video from 2020. The same code was working fine in the video but when I tried this. it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This returns void(`audioPlayer.pause()` future).

```dart
 await audioPlayer.pause();
```

The thing you are trying to do can be get from `PlayerState`.

```dart
if (audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.paused) {
  playing = false;
}

//and
if (audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.playing) {
  playing = true;
}
```